# Can't connect to scrapyd api

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I'm trying to use the scrapyd service to schedule a spider. I'm on mac os 10.9.5. I start the service by running 'Scrapyd', it's running fine and I can navigate to the interface on http://localhost:6800.

But when I try to use the api, for example: curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=somespider

I get the following error:

(7) Failed to connect to localhost port 6800: Connection refused

The spider runs fine using 'scrapy crawl MySpider'.

All help much appreciated!

Comment: what is the result of the command 'scrapyd-deploy -l' ?

Comment: Have you Already tried to use 'sudo' before curl ?

Comment: Hi, if i run 'scrapyd-deploy -l' I get : myProject             http://localhost:6800/, which seems right, and the sudo command guves the same error.

Comment: Apparently you have to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, in case anybody else is getting this error.